# Should i put my Angular Files in same JEE Project?

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, intellij-idea, jax-rs

I'm New To Angular World , I start with some example to use `Angular 2` with `Rest` java Application ( using `jax-rs` )  all these example use 2 project , the first project is a JEE project and the second one is Only Angular

I'm Wondering if i can put my Angular Files In my java project under web folder And Develop it with `intellij IDEA`

Which way is better ?

Comment: yes, you definitely can. And it'll be definitely beneficial because then you'll be able to put all under one project & you have to host only once."How to do" depends on what build tools you are using for BE & FE? If you mention what tools you are using I can put "how". :))

Comment: For Back End I Use Maven Build tool . for angular i'm not sure  i use typeScript Language can you suggest a build tool please ?

Comment: for TypeScript, you should be using some build tool. haven't you run any command to build FE? without knowing that exactly, I can't give a solution.

Comment: i really appreciate your help , when i try to build code i write "npm start"  so my build tool is "npm" i think :)

Comment: npm is nt a build tool, it s just a package manager. I think you are using npm typescript to build. Please check my answer and let me know any issues. :))

Comment: i use webpack build tool

Comment: will update the answer. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You definitely can and it'll be beneficial

- You can include both of them into a single  project.
- You have to host only one.

To do that, you have to integrate your FE build task into BE build tasks. Since you use Maven for BE & NPM TypeScript for FE. You can do by [this.](https://github.com/wmono/tsc-maven-plugin)

Since you can clearly get the idea of the steps need to do, from the source, I'll tell you what this integration is really doing behind the stage.

Basically what you are doing is, adding npm commands into the default Maven commands.

Ex:
After you are done with the plugin integrations

**mvn clean** -> mvn clean + npm clean.

Same will happen for build, run etc.